# How to turn the behaviour of a pythonic function into a proper formal notation

Tags: notation, programming

Coming from a python function I would like to describe a certain behavior in a more formal and general way:

Suppose I have a set of $n$ data points $X = \lbrace x_{1}, ..., x_{n} \rbrace$ where each data point $x \in X$ has a certain time and a certain location. For each data point, I would like to find all other data points which are in a certain temporal and spatial distance. My current attempt looks like this:
$$
\text{ValidPoints(x)}=\lbrace z \in X \mid x \ne z \land \text{TimeDifference(x, z)} <= \mathbf{t} \land \text{Distance(x, z)} <= \mathbf{d} \rbrace
$$
where $\mathbf{t}$ is a certain temporal and $\mathbf{d}$ a certain spatial threshold (for instance: $\mathbf{t} = 10 \ days$ and $\mathbf{d} = 600 \ meters$).

Is this a notation I could use? Also, do I have to define the functions $\text{TimeDifference}$ and $\text{Distance}$? If so, would I define them prior to $\text{ValidPoints}$ or afterward? Would something like "$\text{TimeDifference}(t_{1}, t_{2})$ is defined as the temporal difference between two data points in minutes" be sufficient?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Didn't this already get posted a couple days ago?

Comment: @AaronHendrickson Yes, I asked something similar but reformulated and expanded the question to be more precise.

Comment: Of course, notation is simply a means to denote some model/structure/information. You should use whatever notation suits you best, provided it is easily readable (which, for your case, it is!). Yes, you would need to define the two functions $\text{TimeDifference}(x_1,x_2)$ and $\text{Distance}(x_1,x_2)$ according to the metric you use for time/space. $\text{ValidPoints}$ is suited to be defined as a set according to the definition you've given. Since its definition uses the two functions, it should be clear that the two functions should be defined beforehand. (contd.)

Comment: Alternatively, for a point $\mathbf x\in X$, you can define functions returning sets: $\operatorname{Distance}(\mathbf x,d)$ returns a set of all other points in $X$ within distance $d$ from $\mathbf x$ and $\operatorname{Time}(\mathbf x,t)$ returns a set of all other points in $X$ within temporal distance $t$ of $\mathbf x$ and your desired result is their intersection $\operatorname{Distance}(\mathbf x,d)\cap\operatorname{Time}(\mathbf x,t)=\operatorname{ValidPoints}(\mathbf x)$

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Thank you very much! That helped me a lot. 
Would it be sufficient to define $\text{TimeDifference}$ and $\text{Distance}$ via natural language? E.g. "$\text{TimeDifference}(x_{1}, x_{2})$ is defined as the temporal difference between two data points in minutes." and "$\text{Distance}(x_{1}, x_{2})$ is defined as the distance between two data points in meters."?

Comment: @Gold: For the $\text{Distance}()$ method, defining it as the distance between two data points in meters is fine. However, for the $\text{TimeDifference}()$ method, you need to think how to handle edge cases. (contd.)

Comment: One thing to keep in mind when defining the $\operatorname{TimeDifference}()$ function are examples like the difference between $x_1$.time=$00:00:00$ (on $22-06-21$) and $x_2$.time=$00:30:00$ (on $02-07-21$). The time difference between them is $10$d+$30$min, but on a calendar, they are $10$ days apart, so what do you do?  Another example can be between $x_1$.time=$23:59:00$ (on $22-06-21$) and $x_2$.time=$00:00:00$ (on $03-06-21$) where the time difference between them is $10$d+$60$sec, but on a calendar, they are $11$ days apart.

Comment: Since you're working with Python, I suggest checking out the `datetime` and `collections` module, specifically `datetime.datetime()` for the time object of the data points and `collections.namedtuple()` to define a C-like structure as a datatype `Point` which will hold two objects: a distance (`float`) and a datetime object (`datetime`) and define your points of the set $X$ (`X=set()`) using this custom-defined datatype `Point`.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Great catch, I didn't think of that - thank you! I suppose using the notation $x$.time to reference the time of a data point (like you did) is also fine? I guess I'm worrying way too much about using a "wrong" notation. 
Thank you again!

Comment: @Gold: There's no "wrong" notation if you unambiguously define the notation you're using and there is no logical flaw. Personally, I think storing the data-points as C-like structures (with two values `loc` and `time`/`datetime`) and then defining methods to work on those structures is the most readable way to go following OOP principles. Like I said: whatever suits you best! :)